# How to fully refresh android app after configuration change

Tags: android, android-activity

I want that my activities are recreated from scratch when device cofigs like font size changes or app is launched after killed by OS. What's the best way to achieve this? By default lifecycle methods like onCreate etc are called but activity is not fully initialized.

Comment: "By default lifecycle methods like onCreate etc are called but activity is not fully initialized" -- yes, it is, at least for what most developers would consider "fully initialized" to mean. Please explain **completely and precisely** what you mean, and perhaps provide source code illustrating what you feel is not "fully initialized".

Answer (score 1):

Simply call the [recreate](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#recreate()) method of the Activity:

```
recreate();
```